# Find max number out of arrays and associate string with them

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays containing information about people:

```
brad = ["Brad", 16]
andrew = ["Andrew", 43]
```

The bigger number can be found by:

```
max_num = [brad[1], andrew[1]].max
```

I want to match the name with the maximum so I could say

```
puts "The max is #{max_num} and the record setter is #{name}"
```

How would I go about achieving this? This would have to work for more than two arrays as listed, so an answer of `if max_num == brad[1] else` etc. will not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get by:

```
[brad, andrew].max_by { |k,v| v } # => ["Andrew", 43]
```

So

```
name, max_num = [brad, andrew].max_by { |k,v| v }
puts "The max is #{max_num} and the record setter is #{name}"
```

Comment: Thanks you @xdazz it worked, would you mind explaining what the { |k,v| v } means?

Comment: @JamesMitchell Here `k` will be the name and `v` will be the num, and max_by the num which is `v`.

Comment: ...or `puts "The max is %s and the record setter is %d" % [brad, andrew].max_by { |k,v| v }`.